# How to Update TextBlock after copy a file in FOR Loop in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hi I want copy some file in Hard and after each copy TextBlock increase one number

```
foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(clipsSource, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
     i++;
     File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(clipsSource, Dest + "\\clips"), true);
     copyProgressLbl.Text = i.ToString();
}
```

But TextBlock Not Updated in each loop
What do I do?

Comment: You should use Dispatcher: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.pushframe.aspx

Comment: text block did update but you may perhaps not see it because the loop is executed in main thread.

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample to run the code async and update the TextBlock so it does not block the UI.

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(clipsSource, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        i++;
        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(clipsSource, Dest + "\\clips"), true);
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => copyProgressLbl.Text = i.ToString());
    }
});
```

Idea is to run the blocking methods in Tasks and update the UI controls via Dispatcher when needed.

alternate method using `ThreadPool` if unable to use Tasks

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate
{
    foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(clipsSource, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        i++;
        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(clipsSource, Dest + "\\clips"), true);
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => copyProgressLbl.Text = i.ToString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi I can't run this code in WPF Run not Define and copyProgressLbl.Text = i.ToString() is show errors ?

Comment: you may perhaps need to add `using System.Threading.Tasks;` in the code file. what is the error thrown? which version of .net are you using?

Comment: I use .net 4 and I add using System.Threading.Tasks; but still the Run is not Define

Comment: that is bit strange as Task.Run is defined in assembly mscorlib.dll v4.0.0.0, anyways you may perhaps use the second approach.

Comment: Mr pushpraj It's still not working I changed Dispatcher.Invoke(() => copyProgressLbl.Text = i.ToString()); to  Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => copyProgressLbl.Text = i.ToString())); and code run But still TextBlock not Updated in each loop

Comment: in that case put a break-point and see if it gets called & what is the value. also check if there is any other piece of code which is overwriting the value of textblock.

Answer (score 0):

While @pushpraj had the right idea to call your update code asynchronously, you *might* have more luck using this code instead:

```
foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(clipsSource, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    i++;
    File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(clipsSource, Dest + "\\clips"), true);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => copyProgressLbl.Text = i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: sheridan this code not working. But when I insert a MessageBox in loop block TextBlock is Updated .... I don't Know what should I do!

Comment: Normally in WPF, we *don't* touch UI elements like you are... we data bind properties to the UI element properties, so we'd actually be updating a `string` property here, rather than trying to manually update the `Text` property of a `TextBox` like you are. You could give data binding a go instead.

Comment: Try the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: Sorry Man , Can I Bind 'i' variable to 'Text' property of TextBlock?

Comment: You can bind any `string` value to a `TextBlock.Text` property.